# If $G$ is a group, and there exists an action of $G$ on $X$, then how does $G/H$ look when $H=G_x$?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Suppose there exists an action of $G$ on $X$. Let $x \in X$ and $H = \text{Stab}(x)$ ($\text{Stab}(x)$ being the stabiliser of $x$). We denote $p_x$ a the canonical projection from $G$ to $G/S_x$.

Let $f_x: G \rightarrow \text{Orb}(x)$, $(\text{Orb}(x))$ being the orbit of $x$ defined as $f_x(g) = g \cdot x$.

My question would be what is the form of a class in $G/H$? Usually it looks like $aH$ with $a \in G$, but here $H$ is equal to $\text{Stab}(x)$. If $g \in aH$, then $\exists\, g' \in G$ such that $g' \cdot x = x$ and $g = ag'$. Is that correct? I am pretty confused over here.

Comment: In the third paragraph, doesn't the class $aH$ is such that $a\in G$, instead of it being $a\in X$.

Comment: What is $S_x$? The stabiliser?

Comment: @PrakharGupta Yes, I made the appropriate edit!

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg Yes, I made an edit clarifying that!

Comment: Yes, John, you are correct in what you are thinking. If $g \in aH$ then $g = ag'$ where $g'$ comes from $H$. But as $H$ is the Stabilizer of $x$, hence $g'.x = x$(Property of being Stabilized by g').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is correct.  I think the most elegant way to write the left cosets of $H$ in permutational language is as follows:

$$aH = \{ g \in G \mid g \cdot x = a\cdot x\}.$$

(Proving this equality is a good exercise in understanding the definition of a group action.)